# How to write the following pattern

Tags: python

I am trying to print the following pattern in python but am not getting the desired output :

```
0
2 2 
4 4 4 
6 6 6 6
```

I have already used the following code but am not getting the desired output

```
n = int (input("Enter number : "))
for i in range (n):
    print (i *2 )
```

Comment: Maybe you noticed that it prints each number only once? So, add another loop to print it multiple times.

Comment: Your `i` needs to skip every other number. For that you’ll want to use the `step` argument of `range`. You also don’t want to just multiply by two. You want to multiply by 1 first, then 2, then 3… So you need another number that you keep increasing.

Comment: @deceze Multiplying by 2 achieves the same purpose.

Comment: Ah, d’uh, I was thinking of multiplying strings there…

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n = int (input("Enter number : "))
for i in range (n):
    print (' '.join([str(i * 2) for _ in range(i + 1)]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the number `i+1` times.

```
for i in range (n):
    for _ in range(i+1):
        print (i * 2," ", end='') # print without newlines
    print() # end the line
```

Comment: And then he needs another `print()`. It seems I slowly figure out why I'm not TFGITW, because I implement the code before I post...

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yep, guilty. Although I did test the first print before postiing.

Answer (score 0):

Following simple code could help:

```py
n = int (input("Enter number : "))
j = 1
k = 0
for i in range(n):
    s = str(k)+' '
    print(s*j)
    j += 1
    k += 2
```

if `n = 4`, then it would print the following :

```
0
2 2
4 4 4
6 6 6 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int (input("Enter number : ")) 
count = 1
for i in range (n):
    res = str(i*2) + " "
    print (res * (i+1))
print n
```